# Apache2 load balancing with 2 balancer nodes

Tags: apache-http-server, proxy, tomcat, reverse-proxy, load-balancer

I am trying to set up a simple load balancer with Apache2. Here is the configuration that I have made

```
 ProxyPass       /myapp  balancer://mycluster
    ProxyPassReverse /myapp  balancer://mycluster
    Header add Set-Cookie "ROUTE=%{BALANCER_WORKER_ROUTE}e;" env=BALANCER_ROUTE_CHANGED
    <Proxy balancer://mycluster>
                # WebHead1
                BalancerMember ajp://myip2:8009/myapp  ROUTE=1
                # WebHead2
                BalancerMember ajp://myip1:8009/myapp  ROUTE=2
                Require all granted
                ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
                ProxySet stickysession=ROUTE
     </Proxy>
```

But my application fails to load completely when both the balancer members are enabled. If a comment out one of the members it works fine, either of them.

What happens when I enable both? My base page loads, but all the subsidery files like icons, css, js  don't load. When i check for the the reason i see that, the client is trying to load the child pages without the context "myapp". What is it that am doing wrong here?

Thanks